# Property 'pop' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

How can we use the `pop()` function in React Native Navigation?

```
onPress={() => navigation.pop('Home')}>
```

gives me a TypeScript error that

> Property 'pop' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate the navigation prop that we get from useNavigation

types.ts:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
}
```

your file:

```
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();
```

if the above snippet didn't help try

```
const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
```

if you are using `import { NavigationContext } from '@react-navigation/native';`

```
const navigation = React.useContext<any>(NavigationContext);
```